# using xpath with Expat xml parser

Tags: c

I have used Expat xml parser to parse xml. I need to know whether Expat supports the functionality of xpath i.e if i want to use xpath to modify xml at runtime and to pass the modified xml as a input to an api ( here the api name is mentioned in the xml that was parsed by the exppat parser). here i want to parse the xpath command through expat so please suggest if expat supports this.I  am using c language.

Thanks
priya

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, expat **only** parses XML, which means it does not transform it in any way, so the short answer to your question is **NO**.

Comment: i am not trying to modify the xml using Expat, i want to xpath to modify xml whose commands will be mentioned in xml which will be parsed by expat.

Comment: That is esxactly what I meant: no expat cannot do it for you. Again: it only parses XML. You can do it yourself using expat, by using one of its callback functions (when you detect xpath): you can create another parser and parse the document pointed by xpath.

Comment: Alright so you are saying whenever there a reference to xpath in one of the tag of xml that i am parsing , with expat i can write a handler within which i can tell the code to treat xpath in the way i want to. Moreover is it a bit tricky or as simple as i am wrote other callback function to parse the tag of the input xml.

Comment: It is definitely very tricky (you need to create separate parser in your callback and parse the document pointed by xpath from there, when you're finished parsing it: continue with the original xml document). If you want to do something relatively simple you can try to stay with expat, otherwise you could be better off by trying libxml2.

Comment: actually i already parsed the complete xml using expat now moving to libxml2(which i don't know much) will be a overhead which can be taken into consideration if libxml2 is an easier one or can i use two parser in one solution i.e libxml2 for just xpath and rest of the parsing by expat.